# Reporting changes from child ViewController

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller

If one ViewController inherits from another, how do I update stuff in the child ViewController as the variable changes in the parent ViewController?

```
class ViewControllerOne: UIViewController {

    var timer = Timer()

    var number: Int = 0  

    func updateNumber() {
        number += 1
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(updateNumber), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
}



class ViewControllerTwo: ViewControllerOne {
    // So in this class I want to print to the console when number is 3.
    // How do I check for that from this class?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override `updateNumber` in `ViewControllerTwo`.

```
override func updateNumber() {
    super.updateNumber()

    if number == 3 {
        // do something
    }
}
```